# How to sum elements of a list corresponding to elements of another list in python

Tags: python

I have two lists:

```
a=[25,23,18,28]
```

and

```
b=[1,2,2,3]
```

I want to sum the corresponding values in `a` to similar values in `b`, so it would look like this:

```
return_a=(25,41,28)
return_b=(1,2,3)
```

Sorry for the confusion. Stealing JPeroutek's clarification: It looks to me like he wants only unique values to exist in `return_b`. The values in `a` correspond to those in `b`. Wherever you have a duplicate in `b`, you sum the corresponding `a` values.

Nathan Bartley's answer worked for me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure i understood your intention

Comment: This is not clear at all

Comment: @omri_saadon The intention is to combine all elements in list b with the same value and then to sum the corresponding elements in list a.

Comment: It looks to me like he wants only unique values to exist in `return_b`.  The values in `a` correspond to those in `b`.  Wherever you have a duplicate in `b`, you sum the corresponding `a` values.   Seems to me like a dictionary would be a better approach for your data.

Comment: @JPeroutek that's exactly it. I'm pretty new to this so sorry if I don't know much of the jargon. Any idea of how to implement that?

Comment: Mind [edit]ing the question to make it clearer?

Comment: BTW, your `a` & `b` are tuples, not lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good way to do this would be to use a dictionary. The logic is very much like JPeroutek describes. You go through list b, store the corresponding number in list a, and if you encounter a value in b you've already seen, then you add the new number in a it. You might try something like this to generate it:

```
res = {}
for ix in xrange(len(b)):
    cur_b = b[ix] # grab the next number in b
    cur_a = a[ix] # grab the corresponding number in a
    try: # if we've seen cur_b before then we can add cur_a to it
        res[cur_b] += cur_a 
    except KeyError: # otherwise we've never seen cur_b before so we set it to cur_a
        res[cur_b] = cur_a
```

In case the try & except doesn't make sense you can rewrite those four lines to look like this

```
if cur_b in res:  # this asks if cur_b is in the set of keys of res
    res[cur_b] += cur_a
else:
    res[cur_b] = cur_a
```

This will result in a dictionary that looks like the following:

```
{(1, 25), (2, 41), (3, 28)}
```

It's important to note that the dictionary may not preserve the order that you want. For example:

```
b = [3, 3, 2, 1]
a = [12, 4, 6, 6]
```

would result in

```
{(1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 15)}
```

If ordering is important, this would pose a problem with the next step.

---

You can split the dictionary into ret_a and ret_b by messing with the result of

```
res.items()
```

for instance:

```
ret_a = [t[1] for t in res.items()]
ret_b = [t[0] for t in res.items()]
```

Comment: I tried to clarify some code, in case you haven't seen some of this before.

Comment: The try and except worked. Thank you for your help and explanation.

Comment: 1) Your `res` is a dict, not a set. 2) You should mention that the dict may not preserve the original order. 3) Instead of your `try...except` stuff or `if` blocks you can do `res[cur_b] = res.get(cur_b, 0) + cur_a`. Or use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the `collections` module, but that might be a bit too fancy for the OP. 4) You can use the `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` methods instead of your list comprehensions.

Comment: 1) You're right I was using set colloquially. I will change that
2) Yup.
3) Yeah that would simplify the solution -- arguably more pythonic. I agree that using defaultdict would be overengineering.